# How to start a service in CMD Dockerfile instruction after a USER instruction

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, containers

I want to run a container which:

1. Has a non-root user running it by default (USER Dockerfile instruction)
2. Runs a system service (CMD Dockerfile instruction) as crontab

The simplest thing one can think to is to execute the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nano
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN useradd -u 8877 dockeras
RUN mkdir /home/dockeras
RUN chown -R dockeras /home/dockeras && chmod -R u+rwx /home/dockeras
USER dockeras
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Obviously, the CMD instruction will return an error because the cron service requires to be run by root. How to solve this?

Comment: You can use a simple workaround by creating a startup script that starts both the cron service and your application service like a "startup.sh"

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it like this: Dockerfile and startup.sh

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install nano cron sudo

# Create a non-root user
RUN useradd -u 8877 dockeras && \
    mkdir /home/dockeras && \
    chown -R dockeras /home/dockeras && \
    chmod -R u+rwx /home/dockeras

# Copy the startup script
COPY startup.sh /home/dockeras/startup.sh

# Set the script as executable
RUN chmod +x /home/dockeras/startup.sh

# Switch to the non-root user
USER dockeras

# Set the entry point to the startup script
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/dockeras/startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start cron with sudo
sudo service cron start

# Run your application service here
# Example:
# java -jar /path/to/your/application.jar

# Keep the container running
tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I log into the container, execute `service cron status` and says cron is not running.
I wanted to check what happens when startup.sh executes `service cron start` by adding `service cron start >> log.txt`, but no log.txt is created within the container.

Comment: A further consideration: the startup.sh is executed as a non-root user within the container, isn't it? So, how can I switch to a super user in startup.sh or something like this?

Comment: Yes I update my answer. I added to sudo command before to run cron service

Comment: I have already considered this type of solution and has two problems, in my opinion:
1) sudo has to be installed in my container, which could be not taken as granted (I'm also looking for a general solution to this problem)
2) security
a. I have to prompt the password in plain text in my .sh
b. otherwise, I have to edit the sudoers (if I have installed sudo) file in the container writing something like dockeras ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

It seems to me that all of this is exceeding the purpose.

Comment: Maybe we have changed the ownership and permissions of the cron executable itself, allowing it to be executed by non-root users.

Comment: I can't get the purpose of your comment. What do you mean by maybe?

Comment: I had the idea: the setuid, but it neither worked.
In the Dockerfile I write: RUN chown root /home/myuser/startup.sh RUN chmod +x /home/myuser/startup.sh RUN chmod +s /home/myuser/startup.sh before USER and ENTRYPOINT instructions. So I can run the startup.sh (containing service cron start) as root. This would be great, but actually it turns out that [setuid only works properly with binary files (as a C program) and not with bash scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/why-does-setuid-not-work).